# Do HTTP referrers work for Mobile Application?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, http-referer

I am using Directions api with HTTP Url connection in my Android application. 
I want to restrict an api key.

Does it work if I add HTTP referrer as a restriction?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the Directions API web service in an Android app, then you cannot restrict the API key with HTTP referrers. These only work for API keys used with client-side Web APIs such as [these](https://developers.google.com/maps/apis-by-platform#web_apis).

You cannot restrict your API key by IP address either though, since you are calling it from a mobile application so you may have to use a proxy server. Please see [How to use Google-Directions-Android library with a restricted API key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57196465/how-to-use-google-directions-android-library-with-a-restricted-api-key)

Hope this helps you!