# Error: mobile application is not authorized to use this API key

Tags: android, api, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps API and Direction API in my android app. When I compile it, it gives me the following error for the function onRoutingFaliure.

> This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address XX.XX.XX.XX, with empty referer

```
public void onRoutingFailure(RouteException e) {
        if(e != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong, Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you enabled API for root?

Comment: I have enabled it at the API library. I don't know what you mean as "enable API for root". Do I have something more to do?

Comment: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library

Comment: Yes, I have enabled the API there.

Comment: Are you using correct package ID and correct SHA in Google Console?

Comment: Yes, I have two users(driver, parent) in this app and I get the driver location through firebase and it is shown in the map with parent location. That works totally fine. Now I want to add the route between these two. At this moment I'm getting the error. Up to that, all are fine.

Comment: Directions API is a web service so you cannot use the same Android-restricted API key you use for Maps SDK for Android. Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/57229885/11742502